# How can I tell if my defibrillator has worked?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I tell if the [Defibrillate](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=54732) on-use effect of the [Gnomish Army Knife](http://www.wowhead.com/item=40772) is successful without actually asking the person that I'm attempting the resurrect?

Comment: Fairly certain that you can't.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That's the exact opposite of what I want to hear!

Comment: My experience with it there was no indication that it worked, but it has been a long time since I last used it, so might have been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I use an addon - Shadowed Unit Frames.  It has a resurrection icon that is displayed while res is being cast.  It accomplishes this by using the api function [UnitHasIncomingResurrection](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/UnitHasIncomingResurrection).  Unfortunately, the icon vanishes when the res cast ends.

It is unsuitable for determining if the defibrillator worked.

---

I have reviewed the [api](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api), and the simplest way an addon could accomplish what you're asking for is

1. Some new addon must be loaded on the res target.
2. This new addon uses [ResurrectGetOfferer](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/ResurrectGetOfferer) to find out that you have successfully offered a res.
3. The new addon then whispers you, or an addon on your system, that information.

There might be an addon that does something similiar to this, called [AutoRez](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/project-3488).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to tell if any resurrection attempt has been successful in World of Warcraft is to ask the person you were trying to resurrect. This is the same for all forms of resurrection, be that a casted resurrection, combat resurrection, or one of the other forms of resurrection as an effect of on use on items (as per your question).

In all instances, the target for the resurrection will simply receive the "You have been resurrected [Accept/Cancel]" box but there are no further indications than the resurrection attempt was successful.

Comment: the death knights combat res adds a buff icon to the target so you can see it has been cast.

Comment: [That de-buff](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=97821/void-touched) appears after the person has resurrected, not before they've clicked accept?

Comment: It is applied on cast, not on resurrection, most likely so that multiple death knigths don't wast there insta cast combat res

Comment: There is no mechanic in game to stop you from casting multiple combat resurrections on the same target, the subsequent casts are just wasted (and trigger the cooldown on the cast). The link I linked previously actually agrees with you but points out strange behaviour - [the debuff is applied to the DK's target, regardless of whether the target is the person you cast the combat resurrection on](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=97821/void-touched#comments:id=1588892:reply=497017).

Comment: I never said the game would prevent you from casting. It is the player that has to not cast it.

Comment: Regardless to the `Void-Touched` debuff, there is still no way to know if a resurrection has worked.

Comment: DK res can not fail, only the player can decline the res, so it will always work.

Comment: DK resurrection can fail just like the other battle resurrections - it is perfectly possible to cast a DK resurrection on a target that has a pending druid resurrection, thus wasting it. The only time a battle resurrection cast will fail is when the group has used their designated quantity of battle resurrections for the current encounter, in which case they will receive a "You can no longer resurrect during combat" message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4576/discussion-between-blem-and-pixel)